# on distributional derivatives

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

I am dealing with a real-valued function in one real variable defined on an interval $I$ having distributional derivative a countable sum of Dirac peaks located on a dense subset of $I$ all multiplied by constant weights all of the same sign (all positive or all negative) and I wonder if there is some analogue of the classical theorems in Calculus (stating that if a function has derivative everywhere positive, then it is strictly increasing) allowing me to conclude that my function is injective? I have searched an answer in several sources, but as I am not an expert in the subject I may be missing some trivial explanation or contrexample, so I hope someone may help me answering this question?

Comment: First, you have to interpret your function as a distribution, probably you want $f$ to act on test functions $\varphi\mapsto\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\varphi(x)dx$ which makes sense if $f$ is locally integrable with respect to Lebesgue measure $\lambda_1$. However, two functions $f$ and $g$ which coincide $\lambda_1$-almost everywhere generate the same distribution. The best thing you can thus hope for is that $f$ coincides a.e. with an increasing function.

Comment: What do you mean with constant weights?

Comment: Overall you are just saying that $f(x)=f(0)+\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{w_k}2 sign(x - a_k)$ is strictly increasing on $(u,v)$ when $w_k>0,\sum_k w_k < \infty$ and the $a_k$ are dense in $(u,v)$